# What stats are useful for pistol users?

Tags: neocron

I have been leveling my private eye using pistols, but I don't do much damage.  I was wondering what stats are best for a pistol user to do the most damage, and if there is anything else that will increase my damage.

I'm currently 63/55 and I'm using a spitfire gatling pistol, but struggle to kill anything before it actually kills me, so any help you can give is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[techhaven.org](http://www.techhaven.org/resources/weapon-guides/pistol-guide.html) has the following to say about pistol users:

> Pistols are DEX-based weapons that sacrifice range for light weight, high rate of fire, and higher stopping power. They require little or no Weapon Lore to aim. They do have to be aimed at the target for a certain amount of time to get maximum accuracy.

Your main stat as a pistol user will be P-C (Pistol Combat), you will want as many skill points in this as possible, keeping in mind that higher P-C means more damage and better weapon frequency.

If you're going to be using high tech weapons (laser pistols, pulselasers, plasma pistols, etc) you will also need skill points in the T-C (Tech Combat) ability.

While I disagree that weapon lore is a weak stat for pistol users, you generally do not need as much as you would with rifles - it's down to your personal preference, if you like your weapons to lock on quicker, increase the amount of points you put into weapon lore.

Generally as a pistol user you will be more of a support character, a lot of enemies will kill you really quickly by yourself as pistols have a reasonably short range, but with enemies whose main attack is melee based you can quite easily kite them around. Any fire based enemies (like at CRP or Cycrow Labs/Grant Mines) or energy based enemies (like Hoverbots/Warbots/etc) will kill you pretty quickly, and you will need the assistance either of a PPU or tank to keep the enemy occupied while you do some damage.